# decrease cassandra bootstrap time

Tags: cassandra

**Environment:**
RF=3,Consistency_Level=Local_Quorum.

there are lots of data in cluster,and need take long time to bootstrap a new node.
and sometimes new node must join the cluster,
so I want to decrease the time.I have thought a idea to solve the problem.

when bootstraping a node,seperate "stream data from old node" stage from bootstrap stage.
join the node to token ring.and the new node are  responsible for the range key.it can serve new write request.and the status is "UN",not "UJ".
and do "stream data from old node" as a background task,or use a enable/disable data stream switch.if client request old data,because there are other two replication,so there are no problem even the new node does not the data which it is responsible for.

Comment: Some better formatting or grammar may help us to see what you're actually asking.